# two ListViews in one, android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scrollview, expandablelistview

I'm creating a game in which the user can *create a game* and get *invited to play a game*. I want to show the user a *list of all the games* he has *created* and all the games he has been *invited to play* in *same Fragment*, so the user can chose a game he wants to play.

```
header(my games)
list(first adapter)
header(games i have been invited to play)
list(secong adapter or first adapted but populated with different data)
```

I need to use *different adapters* for both *lists*, as the content will differ a bit from each other. Ideally i would like to do this in *one ListView* if its possible? To keep the content in one ScrollView.

In this case should i use *sectioned ListView*, *ExpandableListView* or in last case scenario *two ListViews in a ScrollView*?

Suggestions, links, tutorials much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `SectionedListAdapter` from [this link here](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-sectioned-headers-in-listviews/) for this potentially.

The adapter holds multiple adapters within it (my games + invited games), and just runs through both using `getView()` to populate the `ListView`